# React-Native: How to open locally bundled binary file

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I'm writing a react-native app, and I want it to deploy with a zip file that contains a device firmware update.

Before letting the user send the update, I need my code to open the zip and do some validation of its contents.

I've found lots of zip-handling NPM packages, so all I need to do is load the file contents so I can feed it to one of these.

- require('./firmware/fw.zip'); <-- packager doesn't include .zip by default
- require('./firmware/fw.pdf'); <-- [gross hack] packager includes pdfs, but the actual result of the require() call is a number: `5`.  I don't know what I can do with this number to get file contents, but I'm pretty sure this require() system is designed for loading images, not binary data.
- ReactNativeFs.openFile('./firmware/fw.zip'); <-- fails with ENOENT
- ReactNativeFs.openFile(`${ReactNativeFs.MainBundlePath}/firmware/fw.zip`); <-- MainBundlePath is `undefined` on android.

This seems like a really basic question, so I'm sure I've missed a piece of documentation somewhere, but I'm heading into my third hour trying to load the contents of this file with no luck.

I'm pretty sure I could manually put the zip file into the appropriate `android` and `ios` resource directories, but that seems like a step down a hard-to-maintain road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this problem again a couple months later (I'm apparently the only guy that needs to package .zips in react-native), and the above answer didn't work out for iOS.  So I encoded the .zips as base64, put them in .js files, then used `import` to get the data from those .js files.  This actually seems like a somewhat hacky but also flexible long-term solution, without having to mess around with platform-dependent file locations.

See whole answer at my new question:  [React-native packager configuration - How to include .zip file in bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065669/react-native-packager-configuration-how-to-include-zip-file-in-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

Modify android/app/build.gradle, and add

```
task copyData(type: Copy) {
    from '../../firmware/fw.zip'
    into 'src/main/assets/raw/firmware'
}
preBuild.dependsOn copyData
```

This will at least ensure that the file gets copied each time you build, and is then available with `ReactNativeFs.readFileAssets('raw/firmware/fw.zip', 'base64')`.  I'm not *entirely* thrilled because I still have to have iOS/android dependent code when loading the file, but at least it's loading now.

Tip: watch out for your syntax in gradle.  `into src/main/assets/myFirmware.zip` will create a DIRECTORY called myFirmware.zip, and put your zip file underneath it.  Then readFileAssets will still fail because it's finding a directory at your path, not a file.