# Read local asset in react-native-fs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I have a file ("static.zip") in the root directory of my react-native project that I'm trying to access it via the [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-) library. Given [this](https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive/blob/master/example/App.js) example, I thought it would be as easy as this on iOS:

```
sourcePath = `${MainBundlePath}/static.zip`
RNFS.readFile(sourcePath)
```

However, the file does not exist on that path. When I look inside at the contents of the MainBundlePath directory, I don't see any assets in there. I also tried adding static.zip to my Xcode project, but that didn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the zip file to my Xcode target got this to work, at least on iOS. I was unable to implement a require() solution I found here: [React-Native: How to open locally bundled binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492089/react-native-how-to-open-locally-bundled-binary-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should manually put the file in to iOS Resource by Xcode and Android Asset by Android Studio, then use this package to load file path https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-asset